# Android - Making Radio Buttons from OnClickListener ImageViews

Tags: android, onclick, imageview, onclicklistener

I'm currently making an app that allows users to give feedback to the client via a radio button method e.g. 1-5 or Poor-Amazing. However the buttons need to be custom images 'smileys'.

I have tried to create my own custom radio buttons but this is very painful and the images are low res because the sizes need to be exact. I decided instead to make several Image Views and use OnClickListeners and everything is going very well.

However I am struggling with how to go about making the OnClickListeners. Basically I want the user to only be able to click one image per question like a radio button would. When they click an image, the image will change to another. But the user should not be able to click two images at the same time, again like a radio button.

I've checked to see if anyone had previously asked this question and could not find anything, sorry if it already has been answered.

Hopefully i've explained it clearly, again sorry if I didn't. This is pretty much my first time posting on here :)

Comment: Are you trying to use buttons instead of radio buttons right?

Comment: No i'm just using ImageViews hoping to be able to attach onClick's to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mantain a logic behind the user choice.
For example:

```
private ImageView[] ratingsImages; //[0-4]
private int selectedRating = -1;

private void selectRatingWithPosition(int position){
    //deselect all the ratings (maybe changing image background)
    selectedRating = position;
    //change background for selected one of ratingsImages[position]
}
```

Now in every OnClickListener of your ImageView you need to call this method providing the correct position, maybe with something similar to this:

```
for (final int i = 0; i < ratingsImages.length(); i++){
    ratingsImages[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectRatingWithPosition(i);
        }
    });
}
```

There are more alternative to this, this is just a starting point.
Don't forget that Android Framework already provide a basic implementation for Rating Bars, check here if you are interested: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html and here for a tutorial on how to use them https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-rating-bar-example/

Comment: Hmm I think I understand what your trying to do, makes sense. Basically i'd just need to call the method for each of the ImageView's?